# Is this sentence grammatically correct? What's the subject of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> In high school, despite studying geology, the subject felt distant and abstract, especially as a student in a mountainous region.

I want to express the meaning that the person studying geology felt that the subject was distant and abstract.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Don't answer in comments. You wrote enough for an answer, *and then* complained that the question won't get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In high school, despite studying geology, the subject felt distant and abstract, especially as a student in a mountainous region.

The subject of this sentence is "the subject." Here's the problem with this sentence. We understand the subject of "studying" to be the subject of the sentence containing it; in other words, the sentence implies that the subject of geology is itself studying geology. Presumably you meant to say that the *student* in question is the one doing the studying. There are many ways to fix this. You could add a separate subject:

> In high school, despite studying geology, **she** felt that the subject was distant and abstract, especially as a student in a mountainous region.

One might wonder why living in a mountainous region would make geology seem more distant and abstract, but presumably context makes that clear.

Comment: The purpose of or need for "_despite studying geology_" is not clear to me in the OP's sentence. Another alternative version is: _In high school, (the subject of) geology felt distant and abstract, especially to her as a student in (from?) a mountainous region_.